# How can I call putchar from the C library using ARM Assembly for the Raspberry pi?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I am having a real hard time trying to call putchar in a loop which prints the first argument sent in via a program written in ARM Assembly for the raspberry pi. e.g. **./myprog1 hello** should output **"hello"** in the console when ran.

The code is as follows:

```
    .text
   .balign 4
   .global main
   main:
       LDR r4, [r1, #4]    @ base address for argv[1] 
       MOV r5, #0          @ counter for loop

   loop:
       LDRB r0, [r4], #1   @ read each char byte in and increment
       CMP r0, #0          @ #0 representing null terminator
       BL putchar
       ADDNE r5, r5, #1
       BNE loop
   end:
       MOV r0, #0
       BX lr
```

I know there are obvious issues but as to where I am not sure. E.g. BL putchar should call putchar and put the next instruction in the link register but upon messing around with that all I get is the first character.

I've consulted resources such as:

https://thinkingeek.com/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi/ and http://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/intro-co-rpi.html but just can't seem to get my head around it. I'm sure it's probably just a simple solution of pushing and popping registers in the right place or something similar but I've been stuck on this for days now and have not been able to progress. The program doesn't even need to output the argument - the loop is meant to calculate the length but I wanted to mess around with it and learn on top of doing that.

This isn't a homework problem per say but in fact a way for me to debug part of a much bigger assignment I need to do.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Flags are not preserved across function calls. You should not put the `BL` between your `CMP` and your conditionals. You presumably don't want to print the terminating zero anyway, so just do something along the lines of `CMP; BEQ end; BL; ADD; B loop`

Comment: I had a feeling this may have been the case also as I remember hearing in the AAPCS that flags arent preserved across function calls a long with r0-r3.

So are you saying it's just down to the structure really?. - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code actually, and they're all related to what is and is not preserved across a call boundary.

[@Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester)'s comment is spot on in terms of your immediate problem: the PSR (which contains the status flags) is not preserved across a call boundary, so the result of your `CMP` is clobbered by the `BL`.

But it's also worth noting that `lr` is clobbered by the `BL` too, so when you reach the end of `main()` the `BX lr` will branch right back to the line after the `BL`.  Your comment suggests that you know that `r0-r3` are call-clobbered.  But `r12` and `lr` are too, so they need preserving if you're using them; and `main()` is a function just like any other, so it needs to conform to the calling conventions by preserving `r4-r11`.

Currently, `main()` is clobbering `r4` and `r5`, so these need to be pushed to the stack at the start and popped at the end, along with `lr` (to avoid the problem of `lr` being clobbered by the `BL`).  The ARM ABI requires 8-byte stack alignment across call boundaries in different translation units, so you'll have to push and pop one other register too to make it an even number.

So, at the start, you'll want

```
main:
    PUSH {r4-r6,lr}
```

and at the end

```
    POP {r4-r6,lr}
    BX lr
```

or equivalently

```
    POP {r4-r6,pc}
```

where the stacked value of `lr` is popped directly into the program counter, which causes a branch.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information! I did wonder why my lab TA had put PUSH {r4-r11} after calling the main and then popping when finished.